# NSStream and NSOperation request (0x1d17cd70) other than the current request(0x0) signalled it was complete on connection 0x1c5f4060

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsstream

I,m using apples QRunLoopOperation

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/PictureSharing/Listings/QRunLoopOperation_m.html

in conjunction with the NSStream file download:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html

The thread i create to which run the loop is ASNetworking style:

```
do
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"FancyThreadName"];

        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runLoop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [runLoop run];
    }
}
while (YES);
```

This works fine most of the time but sometimes I get an "request (0x1cd74ad0) other than the current request(0x0) signalled it was complete on connection 0x1cd48430"
of course with different object numbers. The run loop itself looks like

(void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
(heres an sharp sign)pragma unused(aStream)
    assert(aStream == self.networkStream);

```
switch (eventCode) {
    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
      // I do something - update state etc
    } break;
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        // I Handle the bytes and CLOSE (like in the Apple example -> IS THIS BAD?)
        [self handleBytesAvaialble]:// i can perform [self finishWithError:nil] here
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
        assert(NO);     // should never happen 
    } break;
    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
        //I finish the whole operation and log the error 
        [self finishWithError: someErrorICreate];
    }
        break;
    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
      //This seems to happen before the error 


    } break;
    default: {
        assert(NO);
    } break;
}
```

}

OK Can anybody help me with the solution of this problem? 
What i Think is:

1. Maybe I should not end in handle available bytes and instead end in NSStreamEventEndEncountered ?
2. Perhaps the error is because I finsh the operation in handleBytesAvailable and the end event is scheduled for running, then i start another operation and get the error on it?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: > "Perhaps the error is because I finsh the operation in handleBytesAvailable." This is probably close. But you need to provide more info. When you finish the operation, your stream should not receive any events anymore.

Comment: So when it will not get any more events? Only after the NSStreamEventEndEncountered? I finish the operation when i handle bytes and no more bytes are available (the file is downloaded and it works) in NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable or when an error occurs. The finishWithError: removes the stream from the loop, closes it  and sets it to nil. Should the closing be done on the NSStreamEventEndEncountered instead?

Comment: That doesn't seem correct. When "no more bytes are available", that doesn't mean the data has been send completely. That just means, the sender has not yet sent all bytes, or the bytes are currently transferred somewhere in the middle. You should "tear down" your stream after receiving: `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` or `NSStreamEventErrorOccurred`: first `close` the stream, **then** remove it from the run loop. Only after that, the operation's flag `isExecuting` becomes NO.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering.
It didn't seem right to me too - thus my implication (questions 1,2). 
But why the SimpleFTP example has it like that?

//Set up procedure from the link
        `self.networkStream.delegate = self;
        [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [self.networkStream open];`

Comment: //Tear down 
`self.networkStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        self.networkStream.delegate = nil;
        [self.networkStream close];
        self.networkStream = nil;`

I changed this to close->remove->setDelegateToNil ... seems to work fine for 12000 file downloads. I Do however recall getting and EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the removeFromLoop once ... But I Am testing it now. Furthermore I use the one revision older version of QRunLoop class. Thank you for your help. I'll fill you in on the results.

Comment: Run about 48 000 small file downloads. Unfortunately I got an error. Operation A run before B. Operation A got an StreamEventEndOccured and finished the download. Operation B started and I get StreamOpenEventCompleted then I get The streamEventEndOccured and a moment after that the "request other than..." and EXC_BAD_ACCES when i try to close the stream even thought i have a if(stream!=null) wrapped around it. Any ideas?

Comment: Ensure: removing the stream from the run loop MUST happen on the thread where the run loop is associated with. As well as all other stream methods. Assert also, that the stream you get in the stream handling delegate is actually the stream you expect (pointer comparison). That is, sprinkle generously `assert` macros, as much as possible.

Comment: Yup -> assert(aStream == self.stream) is made in the handling loop.
As for the thread the QRunLoop checks if the thread is the thread reffered to as the "RunLoopThread" if no then it makes a perform selector on thread. Hhmm althouugh i do not recall a check if the "handle event" is made on the initial "schedule" but why would't it be? Anyway I get this error rarely. If i setDelegate->schedule->open then close->remove->delegateNil i get EXC_BAD_ACCES. IF i remove->close->delegateNil i get the event end occured which i can handle with another retry ... Any ideas? Thank you for the help

Comment: From the distance, I can't tell what might be the cause of the issue. But there is definitely one. This requires more info, though: 1) The stack trace and the precise occurrence of the bad access. 2) The *complete* code, including opening, closing, reading from the stream, including `assert` macros.

Comment: 1) The EXC_BAD_ACCES is thrown on [self removeFromRunLoop:stream...] in if(self.stream != null) { **[self removeFromRunLoop:stream...]** -> close -> setDelegateNil}
2) I could provide the whole code but in fact its really the simpleFTP example extracted to a class. Ill try to provide the assertion places etc...